# Passing ref object array from .net to COM server

Tags: c++, .net, com, vb6, marshalling

I'm trying to convert from vb6 to vb.net and I face a picky problem.

I have to pass a reference array object to COM server from vb.net, but variant type of passed array object has VT_DISPATCH, VT_ARRAY only. But, I need a VB_BYREF too.

Below is a method on COM server.

```
    void myCOMSub ( Variant FAR* oArray )
    {
            if ( (VT_DISPATCH | VT_ARRAY | VT_BYREF) == oArray->vt )
                    // success
            else
                    // fail
    }
```

And this is vb6 code before converting.

```
    Dim oOutputArray() As Object

    MyComApp.myComSub(oOutputArray)
```

There was no problem and variant type of oArray always has 3 types well.

So, I converted this part to vb.net like below
        Dim oOutputArray() As Object = New Object() {}

```
    MyComApp.myComSub(oOutputArray)
```

When uses vb.net, oArray in com project has only 2 types excluding VT_BYREF.

As I know, vb6 passed ByRef object as default, but vb.net passed ByVal as default. 
I thinks it needs more work to make a ref object on vb.net. So I googled a lot, but I couldn't find a proper solution for this.

Could you please give me a little help?

Comment: Try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.variantwrapper%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thk, I tried, but VariantWrapper can't be applied to array. :(